# How to execute ajax request one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

Here is my script structure.. & its working fine

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        applyScript();
        var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
        for (i = 0; i < jqueryarray.length; i++) {
             // my logic is here
             try {
                $.ajax({
                   url: url1,
                   cache:  false ,
                   type : 'POST',
                   // dataType: "json",
                   data: data1,
                   success: function(response){
                      if (response) {
                         // some logic with response
                      }
                   }
                });
             }catch (e) { }
        };
    });
</script>
```

Here based on for loop its working ajax sending the request but my goal is i want send the ajax request one after another.

you can see my prob here

[image]

any ideas ?

Comment: Then you can run for loop and make Ajax request synchronous to achieve sequence of Ajax request.

Comment: You are really calling same request many times? Why don't you do only one request to retrieve all relevant datas at once?

Comment: @A.Wolff because of only one request its taking so much of load time to reduce the load time i'm splitting that

Comment: @Naresh But you are paginating it server side or what?

Comment: yeah... its in server side only...

Answer (score 6):

Create a recursive like function that's re called upon completion of one ajax request like below:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    applyScript();
    var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
    var $i = 0; 
    ajax_forloop( $i );
   });
    function ajax_forloop( $i )
    {
         // my logic is here
         try {
            $.ajax({
               url: url1,
               cache:  false ,
               type : 'POST',
               // dataType: "json",
               data: data1,
               success: function(response){
                  if (response) {
                     // some logic with response


                     //call another ajax request
                     $i++;
                     if( $i < jqueryarray.length ) 
                     {
                         ajax_forloop( $i );  
                     }

                  }
               }
            });
         }catch (e) { }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax requests sended asynchronously in your case. And if I correct understand you (you want to post second ajax request after first comlpeted?), you should call second ajax in success (or error) handler of first ajax.

Comment: How will you do that with a `for` loop...?

Comment: I think in this case it is better to use recursive functions instead loop.

Comment: @hi0001234d . Using your code will make the request after the previous finishes right ?or should we use promise instead ? what is the difference ?

Comment: @user1788736 probably you missed with comment. Btw I can answer. You should user promise for guaranteed order of calls. If you just write two calls without it, second function can be called before first finished.